Spacing in between Hexagon tiles

This is my current webpage with hexagons but I'm trying to delete the spacing in between each hexagon row. I want the hexagons to align so that it just looks like a black area on the page. Could someone help me?
The hexagons change a different color when hovered over!


/* General styling */

body,
html {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #886161;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}


/* Container for the honeycomb */

.honeycomb {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 70vw;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Individual hexagon styling */

.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 88.68px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}


/* Hover effect for hexagons */

.hexagon:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: #01003c;
}


/* Offset rows */

.honeycomb .row {
  display: flex;
}

.honeycomb .row:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-left: 50px;
  /* Offset to create the staggered honeycomb look */
}
<!-- Honeycomb container -->
<div class="honeycomb">
  <!-- First Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Second Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Third Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Fourth Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- First Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Second Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Third Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Fourth Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- First Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Second Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Third Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
</div>



You'll have to excuse the little comments as this is a personal project of mine
I tried messing around with the code but got nowhere (it's been a long week). A lot of the tutorials I see online still have that gap in between the rows or columns

There is no space between the rows (Look at the top/bottom corners) It sounds like what you need is actually an overlap.

You can try playing around with the margins on the shapes:
For example:
Add this to .honeycomb .row:nth-child(odd)
margin-bottom: -30px;
margin-top: -30px;


You could use negative margins on all but the first row to overlap the rows:
.row + .row{
  margin-top: -18px;
}

I've also tweaked the offset to get it to line up a bit better horizontally:
.honeycomb .row:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-left: 44px;
  /* Offset to create the staggered honeycomb look */
}



/* General styling */

body,
html {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #886161;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}


/* Container for the honeycomb */

.honeycomb {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 70vw;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Individual hexagon styling */

.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 88.68px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}


/* Hover effect for hexagons */

.hexagon:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: #01003c;
}


/* Offset rows */

.honeycomb .row {
  display: flex;
}

.row + .row{
  margin-top: -18px;
}


.honeycomb .row:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-left: 44px;
  /* Offset to create the staggered honeycomb look */
}
<!-- Honeycomb container -->
<div class="honeycomb">
  <!-- First Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Second Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Third Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Fourth Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- First Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Second Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Third Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Fourth Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- First Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Second Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Third Row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
    <div class="hexagon"></div>
  </div>
</div>



